# Draw Co-ordinates using Turtle

Tags: python, function, loops, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I'm trying to draw a set of co-ordinates using Python `Turtle`, however ,I'm stuck and have no clue how to move on.

```
def generate_map(x_range, y_range, locations):
    generated_map = []

    for x in range(locations):
        generated_map.append([random.randint(x_range, y_range), random.randint(x_range, y_range)])


    return generated_map

 new_generated_map = generate_map(-20,20,10)
 print("The co-ordinates are:",new_generated_map)

def print_map(speed, color, thickness, selected_map):
    print("printing map")


    turtle.speed(3)
    turtle.pencolor("black")
    turtle.pensize(4)


    for locations in (new_generated_map):
        turtle.pendown()
```

I know that I have to set up a loop function but I'm not sure how to write it out, still new to programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to the loop in `print_map`:

```
turtle.goto(locations)
```

Comment: problem fixed  ty

Answer (score 1):

You can use `turtle.setpos()` or `turtle.goto()`, with the coordinates as the arguments:

```
def print_map(speed, color, thickness, selected_map):
    print("printing map")

    turtle.speed(3)
    turtle.pencolor("black")
    turtle.pensize(4)

    for locations in (new_generated_map):
        turtle.setpos(locations)
        turtle.pendown()
```

A few things to note:

1. As there is no `turtle.penup()` in your `for` loop, you only need to call the `turtle.pendown()` method once, outside of the `for` loop, as it saves efficiency. If there is no `turtle.penup()` call in your code at all, then the `turtle.pendown()` can be removed entirely.
2. There is no need to enclose the `new_generated_map` list in brackets in order to loop through the list.

So the improved function would be:

```
def print_map(speed, color, thickness, selected_map):
    print("printing map")

    turtle.speed(3)
    turtle.pencolor("black")
    turtle.pensize(4)

    for locations in new_generated_map:
        turtle.setpos(locations)
```